# how to prevent duplicate outputs when looping through two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop through two arrays at once. the first array contains the headings, the second array contains the data the user has imputed via the form. these values are then set to a pdf file. the problem I am having is that the output is being duplicated twice.

current output

```
first name user input
first name user input
last name user input
last name user input
```

output that I want

```
first name john
last name  smith
```

var dump

```
array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "dkdkd" ["lname"]=> string(3) "kdk" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "dkdkd" ["lname"]=> string(3) "kdk" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "dkdkd" ["lname"]=> string(3) "kdk" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(3) { ["fname"]=> string(5) "dkdkd" ["lname"]=> string(3) "kdk" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

code

```
<?php require('fpdf.php');?>
<?php

$headings = [
    "first_name" => "first Name",
    "last_name" => "last Name",
];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    foreach ($headings as &$value) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $data) {
            if($key == 'submit') {
                continue;
            }    

            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
            $pdf->write(40,"$value");
            $pdf->write(40,"$data");
            $pdf->ln(10);
        }
    }
    $pdf->Output();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add some more information to the question (there is an `edit` link, _use it!_): what output do you get and what is wrong with that?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that edit improves the question. It is obvious that you do _not_ want to use two loops inside each other, that obviously has to double things. It is still unclear what purpose the inner loop serves though which is why we cannot really give a simple answer.

Comment: the inner loop is looping through the data entered by the user

Comment: Show us an example to the data contained in `$_POST`

Comment: Can you post a dump of `$_POST`

Comment: i have posted the var dump results

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is unexpected behavior because the second loop should be repeated as first name, last name, first name, last name. ([see what I mean here](https://3v4l.org/qZAas)).

```
$heading = ['first name', 'last name'];
```

The above snippet of your code shows that you have 2 entries in your array. Therefore, your inner `foreach()` loop will be repeated twice since it is wrapped inside it. A better understanding:

```
foreach(... as ...) // 2 entries
   foreach(... as ...) // 3 entries that will be repeated twice ^
```

You can achieve this using Array index's with a counter.

```
$i = 0; // index start at 0

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if($k == "submit") continue;

    $pdf->write(40, $heading[$i++]);
    $pdf->write(40, $v);
    [...]
}
```

Hope this helped your duplication issue. 
**tldr:** [See it working here](https://3v4l.org/6AkBX).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$duplicate = array();
foreach ($... as $...):
    if (in_array($...., $duplicate))
    continue; //if we already have that id, skip it
    $duplicate[] = $...;
endforeach
```

Hope this helps.